# Whats a good way to set up a QT-Subdir project with Plugins? (outputdir/includes)

Tags: qt

My questions breack down in subquestions, but since all of them concern the same toppic of subdir-projekt setup and some decissions might influence the other questions i ask them all in one post.

1) Can i avoid writing the same include ines in every part using the same libs.

```
INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/../MyLib1    # add header for usage
# Adds the QtQuickSampleLib.lib to the linker
win32:CONFIG(release, debug|release): LIBS += -L$$OUT_PWD/../MyLib1/release/ -lMyLib1
else:win32:CONFIG(debug, debug|release): LIBS += -L$$OUT_PWD/../MyLib1/debug/ -lMyLib1
```

2) How to set up the output paths, so the dynamic-libs and Plugins can be loaded easely.
3) Can the Interface-Definition be placed in e seperate projekt, generating a static output so i can import it easely?

As i understand the Sourceprojekt-Folders schould be setup like this:

```
MainProjekt
+Main-Runner <generates the ELF>
+CoreLib (Most logic in a Lib for easyer tests, might make it a Plugin)
| +SRC
| +Test
+PluginInterface (currently .pri file)
+Plugins
| +PluginA
| | +SRC (Most logic in a Lib for easyer tests)
| | +Test
| +PluginB
| | +SRC (Most logic in a Lib for easyer tests)
| | +Test
| +PluginC <Depends on PluginA & PluginB being loaded>
| | +SRC (Most logic in a Lib for easyer tests)
| | +Test
```

PS: The idear is something like:

PluginA being hardwareInteraction (if possible having a "Fake-Version" for the test in PluginC)

PluginB Handles a Visible Data-Modell

PluginC is a Control-System Talking to the hardware and writing out Data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick is to create a top-level `.qmake.conf` file and use it to define global paths:

```
CONFIG += c++11 #example, now it is set in every pro file
PROJ_VERSION = 1.0.0

OUT_ROOT = $$shadowed($$PWD)
LIB_OUT = $$OUT_ROOT/lib
PLG_OUT = $$OUT_ROOT/plugins
# ...
```

create that file as `.qmake.conf` in the MainProject folder. As long as you compile the project by using the MainProject.pro file, it is used for all sub pro files as well (recursively)

Now for the actual questions:

1.) Create a small pri file in the project root folder as:

```
INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/MyLib1
win32:CONFIG(release, debug|release): LIBS += -L$$LIB_OUT -lMyLib1
else:win32:CONFIG(debug, debug|release): LIBS += -L$$LIB_OUT -lMyLib1d
```

you can include it in all the sub projects that need it. `$$PWD` is always the pri files directory itself, not where it is included. `$$LIB_OUT` is taken from the .qmake.conf

2.) As you might have noticed I defined a few variables in the conf file. You can now use these as `DESTDIR` in the actual pro files. For example, in your lib pro file you can use:

```
VERSION = $$PROJ_VERSION  #optionally use the globally defined version
DESTDIR = $$LIB_OUT
```

You can do the same for plugins, binaries, etc.